# Creating a lot of objects in a tile-based game

Tags: c++, performance, beginner, c++11

I am working on an SDL2 based isometric, tile-based engine for a SimCity 2000 Clone.

Basically I'd really appreciate if someone with experience could review my code and point out weak points since I'm not an experienced C++ dev.

[Here is my repository](https://github.com/JimmySnails/IsometricEngine).

But I do have a specific part I'd like you to review. In my `Cell` class, each object represents a map tile with informations like `tileID` (texture to render), and later attributes like "hasPower, water, ..."

It is quite complex and has a lot of member functions. My game is a SimCity 2000 clone and tiles can be elevated. so a cell must check its surrounding tiles if they're elevated, and if so draw a different texture (`tileID`) according to its neighbors elevation or even raise / lower itself.

The rendering is also done in the `Cell` class because the sprite object must know its ISO coordinates (including the height) which is known per cell object.

I could rewrite my code, so that the rendering is done in the `vectorMatrix` class (in a loop that iterates over all cells in the vector, gets the cell's height, sets the sprites isocoordinates, and then calls the sprites `render()` function), but I've tried that and it makes no performance difference.

## Cell.hxx

```
#ifndef CELL_HXX_
#define CELL_HXX_

#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>

#include "SDL2/SDL.h"


#include "sprite.hxx"
#include "basics/point.hxx"
#include "basics/resources.hxx"

/** @brief Class that holds map cells
 * Each tile is represented by the map cell class.   
 */
class Cell
{
public:
  Cell();
  explicit Cell(Point isoCoordinates);
  ~Cell();

  /** @brief get Sprite
    * get the Sprite* object for this cell
    * @see Sprite
    */
  Sprite* getSprite();

  /// get iso coordinates of this cell
  Point getCoordinates();

  /// Sets the neighbors of this cell for fast access
  void setNeighbors(std::vector<Cell*> neighbors);

  /** @brief Increase Height
    * Increases the height of this map cell and checks which
    * tileID must be drawn for each neighbor
    */
  void increaseHeight();
  /** @brief Decrease Height 
    * Decreases the height of this map cell and checks which 
    * tileID must be drawn for each neighbor
    */
  void decreaseHeight();

  /** @brief set Tile ID 
    * Change the texture of the map cell to a specific tile id
    * @see Resources#readTileListFile
    * @param tileID The tileID that should be rendered for this map cell
    */
  void setTileID(int tileID);
  /** @brief get Tile ID
    * Retrieves the current Tile ID of this map cell
    * @return Returns the current Tile ID as Integer
    */
  int getTileID();

private:
  Point _isoCoordinates;
  Sprite* _sprite;

  std::vector<Cell*> _neighbors;
  SDL_Renderer* _renderer;
  SDL_Window* _window;

  int _heightOffset = 20; // Offset for Y Coordinate between two height levels
  int _tileID;
  int _maxCellHeight = 32;

  /** \brief: determine which tile ID should be drawn for this cell
    * Checks all the neighbors and determines the tile ID of this mapcell according to it's
    * elevated / lowered neighbors.
    */
  void determineTile();

  /** \brief set tileID for each neighbor
    * After a cell is raised / lowered, each neighbor must check which tileID it should have
    * @see Cell#drawSurroundingTiles
  */
  void drawSurroundingTiles(Point isoCoordinates);

  /** Enum (bitmask) for mapping neighbor tile positions
    * [ T B L R TL TR BL BR ]
    * [ 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0 ]

    * Our neighbor tiles look like this
    * 2 5 8  
    * 1 X 7
    * 0 3 6
    */

  enum elevatedTilePosition : unsigned int{
       NO_NEIGHBORS = 0x0,
       ELEVATED_TOP = 0x1,
       ELEVATED_BOTTOM = 0x2,
       ELEVATED_LEFT = 0x4,
       ELEVATED_RIGHT = 0x8,
       ELEVATED_TOP_LEFT = 0x10,
       ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT = 0x20,
       ELEVATED_BOTTOM_LEFT = 0x40,
       ELEVATED_BOTTOM_RIGHT = 0x80,
  };

  /** UInt to elevate store tile position in */
  unsigned int _elevatedTilePosition;


  /** Map neighbor tile combinations to tile ID for terrain keytiles. */
  std::map<unsigned int, int> keyTileMap =
  {
    { NO_NEIGHBORS, 14 },
    { ELEVATED_TOP, 3 },
    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM, 5 },
    { ELEVATED_RIGHT, 1 },
    { ELEVATED_LEFT, 7 },
    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM_RIGHT, 2 },
    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM_LEFT, 8 },
    { ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT, 0 },
    { ELEVATED_TOP_LEFT, 6 },

    { ELEVATED_TOP | ELEVATED_TOP_LEFT, 3 },
    { ELEVATED_TOP | ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT, 3 },
    { ELEVATED_TOP | ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT | ELEVATED_TOP_LEFT, 3 },
    { ELEVATED_TOP_LEFT | ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT, 3 },

    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_LEFT, 5 },
    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_RIGHT, 5 },
    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_RIGHT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_LEFT, 5 },
    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM_LEFT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_RIGHT, 5 },

    { ELEVATED_LEFT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_LEFT, 7},
    { ELEVATED_LEFT | ELEVATED_TOP_LEFT, 7},
    { ELEVATED_LEFT | ELEVATED_TOP_LEFT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_LEFT, 7},
    { ELEVATED_TOP_LEFT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_LEFT, 7},

    { ELEVATED_RIGHT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_RIGHT, 1 },
    { ELEVATED_RIGHT | ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT, 1 },
    { ELEVATED_RIGHT | ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_RIGHT, 1 },
    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM_RIGHT | ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT, 1 },

    { ELEVATED_TOP | ELEVATED_LEFT, 9 },
    { ELEVATED_TOP | ELEVATED_LEFT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_LEFT, 9 }, 
    { ELEVATED_TOP | ELEVATED_LEFT | ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT, 9 },
    { ELEVATED_TOP | ELEVATED_LEFT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_LEFT | ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT, 9 },
    { ELEVATED_TOP | ELEVATED_LEFT | ELEVATED_TOP_LEFT, 9 },
    { ELEVATED_TOP | ELEVATED_LEFT | ELEVATED_TOP_LEFT | ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT, 9 },
    { ELEVATED_TOP | ELEVATED_LEFT | ELEVATED_TOP_LEFT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_LEFT, 9 },
    { ELEVATED_TOP | ELEVATED_LEFT | ELEVATED_TOP_LEFT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_LEFT | ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT, 9 },
    { ELEVATED_TOP | ELEVATED_LEFT | ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT | ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT, 9 },

    { ELEVATED_TOP | ELEVATED_RIGHT, 10 },
    { ELEVATED_TOP | ELEVATED_RIGHT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_RIGHT, 10 },
    { ELEVATED_TOP | ELEVATED_RIGHT | ELEVATED_TOP_LEFT, 10 },
    { ELEVATED_TOP | ELEVATED_RIGHT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_RIGHT | ELEVATED_TOP_LEFT, 10 },
    { ELEVATED_TOP | ELEVATED_RIGHT | ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT, 10 },
    { ELEVATED_TOP | ELEVATED_RIGHT | ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT | ELEVATED_TOP_LEFT, 10 },
    { ELEVATED_TOP | ELEVATED_RIGHT | ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_RIGHT, 10 },
    { ELEVATED_TOP | ELEVATED_RIGHT | ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT | ELEVATED_TOP_LEFT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_RIGHT, 10 },
    { ELEVATED_TOP | ELEVATED_RIGHT | ELEVATED_TOP_LEFT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_RIGHT, 10 },

    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM | ELEVATED_RIGHT, 13 },
    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM | ELEVATED_RIGHT | ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT, 13 },
    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM | ELEVATED_RIGHT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_LEFT, 13 },
    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM | ELEVATED_RIGHT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_RIGHT, 13 },
    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM | ELEVATED_RIGHT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_RIGHT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_LEFT , 13 },
    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM | ELEVATED_RIGHT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_RIGHT | ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT , 13 },
    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM | ELEVATED_RIGHT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_RIGHT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_LEFT | ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT , 13 },
    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM | ELEVATED_RIGHT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_LEFT | ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT, 13 }, 
    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_LEFT | ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT, 13 }, 

    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM | ELEVATED_LEFT, 11 },
    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM | ELEVATED_LEFT | ELEVATED_TOP_LEFT, 11 },
    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM | ELEVATED_LEFT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_RIGHT, 11 },
    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM | ELEVATED_LEFT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_LEFT, 11 },
    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM | ELEVATED_LEFT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_LEFT | ELEVATED_TOP_LEFT, 11 },
    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM | ELEVATED_LEFT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_LEFT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_RIGHT, 11 },
    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM | ELEVATED_LEFT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_LEFT | ELEVATED_TOP_LEFT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_RIGHT, 11 },
    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM | ELEVATED_LEFT | ELEVATED_TOP_LEFT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_RIGHT, 11},
    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM | ELEVATED_LEFT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_RIGHT | ELEVATED_TOP_LEFT, 11 },

    //diagonal tiles - insert a block
    { ELEVATED_TOP_LEFT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_RIGHT, 4},
    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM_LEFT | ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT, 4},


    // special cases - elevate the tile
    { ELEVATED_RIGHT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_LEFT, -1},
    { ELEVATED_RIGHT | ELEVATED_TOP_LEFT, -1},
    { ELEVATED_LEFT | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_RIGHT, -1},
    { ELEVATED_LEFT | ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT, -1},
    { ELEVATED_TOP | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_LEFT, -1},
    { ELEVATED_TOP | ELEVATED_BOTTOM_RIGHT, -1},
    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM | ELEVATED_TOP_LEFT, -1},
    { ELEVATED_BOTTOM | ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT, -1}

  };
};


#endif
```

## Cell.cxx

```
#include "cell.hxx"

Cell::Cell()
{

}

Cell::Cell(Point isoCoordinates) : _isoCoordinates(isoCoordinates)
{
  _renderer = Resources::getRenderer();
  _window = Resources::getWindow();

  // Default Floor sprite has tileID 14
  _tileID = 14;

  _elevatedTilePosition = 0;
  _sprite = new Sprite(_tileID, _isoCoordinates);
}


Cell::~Cell()
{

}

Sprite* Cell::getSprite()
{
  return _sprite;
}

void Cell::setNeighbors(std::vector<Cell*> neighbors)
{
  _neighbors = std::move(neighbors);
}

void Cell::renderCell()
{
  if (_sprite != nullptr)
  {
    _sprite->setTileIsoCoordinates(_isoCoordinates);
    _sprite->render();
  }
}

Point Cell::getCoordinates()
{
  return _isoCoordinates;
}

void Cell::drawSurroundingTiles(Point isoCoordinates)
{
  int tileHeight = _isoCoordinates.getHeight();

  for (int i = 0; i < _neighbors.size(); i++)
  {
    if ( _neighbors[i] != nullptr )
    {
      _neighbors[i]->determineTile();

      // there can't be a height difference greater then 1 between two map cells.
      if ( tileHeight - _neighbors[i]->getCoordinates().getHeight() > 1 
      &&   Resources::getTerrainEditMode() == Resources::TERRAIN_RAISE
      &&   i % 2 )
      {
        _neighbors[i]->increaseHeight();
      }
      if (  tileHeight - _neighbors[i]->getCoordinates().getHeight() < -1 
      &&    Resources::getTerrainEditMode() == Resources::TERRAIN_LOWER
      &&    i % 2) 
      {
        _neighbors[i]->decreaseHeight();
      }
    }
  }
  // call for this tile too. 
  determineTile();
}

void Cell::increaseHeight()
{
  int height = _isoCoordinates.getHeight();

  if ( height < _maxCellHeight )
  {
    _isoCoordinates.setHeight(_isoCoordinates.getHeight() + 1);
    drawSurroundingTiles(_isoCoordinates);
  }
}

void Cell::decreaseHeight()
{
  int height = _isoCoordinates.getHeight();

  if ( height > 0 )
  {
    _isoCoordinates.setHeight(height - 1);
    drawSurroundingTiles(_isoCoordinates);
  }
}

void Cell::determineTile()
{
  _elevatedTilePosition = 0;
  int tileHeight = _isoCoordinates.getHeight();

  for (int i = 0; i < _neighbors.size(); i++) //determine TileID
  {
    if ( _neighbors[i] != nullptr )
    {
      if ( _neighbors[i]->getCoordinates().getHeight() > tileHeight )
      {
        switch (i)
        {
          case 0: _elevatedTilePosition |= ELEVATED_BOTTOM_LEFT; break;
          case 1: _elevatedTilePosition |= ELEVATED_LEFT; break;
          case 2: _elevatedTilePosition |= ELEVATED_TOP_LEFT; break;
          case 3: _elevatedTilePosition |= ELEVATED_BOTTOM; break;
          case 5: _elevatedTilePosition |= ELEVATED_TOP; break;
          case 6: _elevatedTilePosition |= ELEVATED_BOTTOM_RIGHT; break;
          case 7: _elevatedTilePosition |= ELEVATED_RIGHT; break;
          case 8: _elevatedTilePosition |= ELEVATED_TOP_RIGHT; break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  auto keyTileID = keyTileMap.find(_elevatedTilePosition);

  if ( keyTileID != keyTileMap.end() )
  {
    _tileID = keyTileID->second;
  }

  // special case: if both opposite neighbors are elevated, the center tile also gets elevated
  if ((( (_elevatedTilePosition & ELEVATED_LEFT) && (_elevatedTilePosition & ELEVATED_RIGHT) )
  ||   ( (_elevatedTilePosition & ELEVATED_TOP) && (_elevatedTilePosition & ELEVATED_BOTTOM) )
  ||      _tileID == -1 )
  &&      Resources::getTerrainEditMode() == Resources::TERRAIN_RAISE)
  {
    increaseHeight();
    _tileID = 14;
  }

  if ((( (_elevatedTilePosition & ELEVATED_LEFT) && (_elevatedTilePosition & ELEVATED_RIGHT) )
  || (   (_elevatedTilePosition & ELEVATED_TOP)  && (_elevatedTilePosition & ELEVATED_BOTTOM) )
  ||      _tileID == -1 )
  &&      Resources::getTerrainEditMode() == Resources::TERRAIN_LOWER)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < _neighbors.size(); i++)
    {
      if ( _neighbors[i] != nullptr )
      {
        if ( _neighbors[i]->getCoordinates().getHeight() > tileHeight )
        {
          _neighbors[i]->decreaseHeight();
        }
      }
    }
    _tileID = 14;
  }
  _sprite->changeTexture(_tileID);
}

void Cell::setTileID(int tileID)
{
  _sprite->changeTexture(_tileID);
  _tileID = tileID;
}

int Cell::getTileID()
{
  return _tileID;
}
```

I do have a vector matrix class for easy access of Cells at specific ISO coordinates.

When I start the game, the matrix is filled with Cell objects (they live throughout the game and are accessed often). The vectormatrix itself is quite fast, but this `for` loop takes quite some time. (In VS2017 debug mode on my laptop it's about 4,6 seconds for 128x128 tiles!) I've debugged the code and it's exactly this Line that takes so long.

```
  int z = 0;
  // initialize cell Matrix

  // DEBUG TIMER START
  for (int x = 0; x <= _map_size; x++)
  {
    for (int y = _map_size; y >= 0; y--)
    {
      z++;
      Cell* mapCell = new Cell(Point(x, y, z));
      _floorCellMatrix.addCell(x, y, mapCell);
    }
  // DEBUG TIMER END: ~4600 ms
  }
```

I found [this article](https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/2-major-reasons-why-modern-c-is-a-performance-beast) but I don't understand if this is applicable for my use-case or if that's a different story.

I've also read that the `new` operator should be avoided if possible, but I also don't really know how to implement this.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, i thought this is enough because it could be related to the new operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like quite an endeavor!  I miss Sim City 2000.  I even bought an Android version for $5 and then they took it away!

Good luck on this project.

---

Writing identifiers with a leading underscore is a bad idea, and is generally dissuaded as a style. Note that it is legal for member names if (and only if) the next character is not a capital letter or another underscore.

---

You have a default constructor for `Cell` which is empty!  So what about all the raw pointer data members?

---

[NL.9: Use `ALL_CAPS` for macro names only](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#nl9-use-all_caps-for-macro-names-only)

---

You will need to define `keyTileMap` in one CPP file; you should move the huge initialization stuff to there, too.

---

In the constructor, use the member init list, not assignments in the body of the function.  Some of those can be default initializers on the data members (tileID, elevatedTilePosition).

---

Don’t define an empty destructor.  Let the compiler supply it; it will generate better code that way.  If you must, just declare it as `=default` in the class.

---

Many of the simple functions should be inline in the class definition.  e.g. `{ return sprite; }`.

---

```
void Cell::setNeighbors(std::vector<Cell*> neighbors)
{
  _neighbors = std::move(neighbors);
}
```

OK, here is a tricky one!  **Do not** treat this as a “sink” parameter!  That is only for when you know a new object needs to be created (e.g. in constructors), not for when an existing object is reused.

You are forcing a full copy of `neighbors` complete with a block of memory, and deleting the memory block that `_neighbors` already held.  Regular assignment would *reuse* this existing block of memory, if it fit.

I’ve seen a presentation with benchmarks, but I don’t recall who gave it now.

---

```
_sprite = new Sprite(_tileID, _isoCoordinates);
```

[⧺C.149](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c149-use-unique_ptr-or-shared_ptr-to-avoid-forgetting-to-delete-objects-created-using-new) — no naked `new` or `delete`.

You should probably make this a `unique_ptr` as a drop-in replacement without otherwise changing the architecture.

---

```
if (_sprite != nullptr)
```

Don’t write explicit tests against `nullptr`.  Use the contextual conversion to bool, or in this case, the `operator!`.

```
if (!_sprite)
```

---

```
for (int i = 0; i < _neighbors.size(); i++)
```

Don’t go through the collection by index.  Look how many times you use `neighbors[i]` in the block of code!  Use the range-`for` construct to iterate directly over the vector!

```
for (auto n : _neighbors) {
  ⋮
```

(Note that if you change your vector to hold values rather than pointers, you will make that `auto&`)

---

Your ELEVATED constants are bitmapped, right?  So you can combine them.

```
(_elevatedTilePosition & ELEVATED_LEFT) && (_elevatedTilePosition & ELEVATED_RIGHT)

 constexpr auto LEFT_and_RIGHT = ELEVATED_LEFT|ELEVATED_RIGHT;
 (_elevatedTilePosition & LEFT_and_RIGHT == LEFT_and_RIGHT)
```

The && is a short-circuit operation, so the code has to jump.  Jumps are slow.  Testing that both bits are set is the same speed as testing one!

---

```
std::vector<Cell*> _neighbors;
```

The set of neighbors is fixed, right?  Like, 8 of them, not more?

The `vector` will allocate memory separately.  Use a fixed-size array instead.

I don’t know what you are using for the matrix.  It may, however, be overly complex.  If you use a flattened linear vector instead of a 2D array (or vector of vectors) you can move around to neighbors quickly by using *strides*.  So, you might not need to store this member at all, but will build it on the fly with simple arithmetic.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I'll update my code with your suggested changes! I already have a branch with a flat vector but I didn't notice any difference in performance, that's why I didn't merge it. I haven't heard of _strides_ yet, but i'll look into it! You suggest that the vector should hold values instead of pointers, wouldn't that slow down vector operations? Btw, if you love SC2K as much as I do, you could join my project. I've set up a discord server.

Comment: I’m thinking of posting a sample of *strides*, on one of the recent tic-tac-toe answers.  Why would having larger elements slow down vector operations?  Do you mean inserting/splicing etc?  I did not know you were doing that.

Comment: No, I'm not doing that. I assumed that it's faster with pointers because they are smaller, thanks for clarifying! A stride-example for finding the neighbors would be greatI I've started reading about _strides_ but I'm not yet entirely sure how to implement that.

Comment: It is faster to recopy memory to insert into the vector (once, when inserting) than to have a non-local memory access every time any element is *accessed*.  See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo slide at 5:08 etc. for "compact layout"

Comment: Continue discussion in chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44768562#44768562

Comment: It seems that the chat doesn't display my messages... would you mind joining the projects discord server to talk about the details? I've already implemented a lot of your suggested changes, but i don't know how how to improve the getNeighbors() function

Answer (score 3):

To address your concern about using `new` the answer is don't. Creating an object without new simply requires calling the constructor. You will then use [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2321511/5416291) to manage the lifetime of your objects. There may come a day when you need objects to persist beyond their scope but you shouldn't today.

This:

```
Cell* mapCell = new Cell(Point(x, y, z));
_floorCellMatrix.addCell(x, y, mapCell);
```

Can be changed to:

```
_floorCellMatrix.addCell(x, y, Cell(Point(x, y, z)));
```

And any other `new`'s can likely be similarly removed. The article you linked is about smart pointers which have mostly replaced the use of `new` and `delete`. It is an important subject. Read up on it.

Your performance problem is either in your Cell constructor or the vectormatrix addCell() method.

- Dont name anything with a leading underscore _. Many uses of the leading underscore are reserved and the [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/5416291) are complicated. If you choose to use them anyway be thorough about how it works but it is common to simply avoid them and save the headache.
- Don't declare empty constructors and destructors. Especially since you don't want to create any Cells without the use of parameters.
- You are using pointers, not references, to your window and renderer, however that should not deliver a significant performance hit.
- I would still argue that the Cell class should know nothing about how it's drawn and that the renderer and window should iterate over the vectormatrix and handle that. The vectormatrix shouldnt do that either. There is a concept called [SRP or Single Responsibility Principle](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/17100/297895) that suggests these classes need to know about their jobs and thats it.
- Lastly you are creating your keyTileMap *every* single time you make Cell. That has to be your performance hit.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately if i change the line like you suggested, i get an "conversion from Cell to Cell* is not possible" error message. I've also removed the SDL renderer / window from the constructor (which was only a refence from the resources class and not even used...) and moved the rendering process to the vectorMatrix class but it wasn't any faster. I clarified in my question that i measured that the performance problem is the the `for` loop with the new operator.

Comment: @Chris Yes because it is no longer a pointer and just an object. Ill redo the answer later this evening.

Comment: @Chris to fix the conversion issue you will have to store the Cells directly in your matrix as apposed to pointers. `std::vector<Cell>` instead `std::vector<Cell*>`

Comment: I've read somewhere that it's more efficient to store pointers in a vector instead of objects. If that's not the case i'll change that!

Comment: @Chris How? you have to create a new object each time and then additionally have to create a pointer. pointers are small so it doesn't hurt you but it isn't a benefit size wise. vectors do some resizing behind the scenes and that uses copying and movement that could be costly but you preallocate the size of your vectors because you know how many objects you need. And really at the end of the day RAII does clean-up for you and that's what you want to get into the habit of doing. If you insist on using pointers they should be smart pointers. (If there's some other efficiency please link.)